# Using JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize

Tags: javascript, serialization, selectlist

I'm using the Deserialize method of the JavaScriptSerializer class to deserialize a list of custom objects (i.e. List).  Within the SalesOrderLineItemResult class is a property of type "SelectList" that apparently cannot be deserialized - gives an error of:

*Type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' is not supported for deserialization of an array*

Is there a way to either get this .Net type to deserialize or to mark the property to indicate that it should be skipped (ScriptIgnore doesn't work)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I faced almost the same problem and I ended up using `List<SelectListItem>` (which deserialize perfectly fine) instead of built-in `SelectList`.